# Directadmin Subdomain with another rootdir

Tags: apache, subdomain

I have some problems with setting up a subdomain. Not sure if i'm here on the right place to ask this question. So not please refer me.

What I want:
I want a subdomain on my website pointing to an other dir in my user home dir

What I get:
If I go to the subdomain I will reach the normal dir of the current domain

What I tried:
On the directadmin admin panel I went to `Httpd.conf Customization` I selected my domain and i filled in the next information:

```
    ServerName subdomain.|DOMAIN|
    DocumentRoot |HOME|/domains/subdomain/public_html
```

What do I do wrong or what do I miss?

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way to do this in DirectAdmin is to create the subdomain as new domain (just like you created the domain itself).